# Python MongoDB clob exception

Tags: python, mongodb

I am Migrating the data from oracle to Mongo DB using python,  while migrating i am able to           read the clob object using clob.read(), but while inserting into mongo DB it is throwing an   exception saying

> Traceback (most recent call
>   last):     File "test.py", line 39, in    db.test234.insert(i)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\sitepackages\pymongo\collection.py", line 409,
>   in insert gen(), check_keys,self.uuid_subtype, client)
>   InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8:
>   'Malicious Attack   Driver\r\n
>   -----------------------\r\n\r\n

This is an effort to   (Malicious attack  driver) comprising of wrapper routines to provide test script infrastructure to  run    different   attack tools,vulnerability scanners,hacker tools such as . The objective is to provide common APIs across all the protocols which can run the attack/test from a remote.

```
'REVIEW_DESCRIPTION', type 'cx_Oracle.CLOB', -1, 4000, 0, 0, 0
```

checked many forums and stack overflow , unable to find the exact solution for the issue, tried options like encoding the clob data which still thrown same exception

Comment: Did you try encoding the data into utf-8 using pythom then inserting it into the mongodb

Comment: Try to build a minimal example and post all information (string to be inserted, your complete Python code, used MongoDB version etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data to UTF8, so you need to know what encoding is used in the Oracle DB. First decode, and then encode to UTF8. For example, if the data is written in `latin1` in the Oracle DB:

```
unicode_representation = oracle_representation.decode('latin1')
utf8_representation = unicode_representation.encode('utf8')
```

You should be able to store `utf8_representation` now.